# draw texture on 4 vertices plane

Tags: unity-game-engine, blender

i have a standard plane created with unity and replaced its mesh filter (that had 121 tri, 202 vertices) with a mesh filter made in blender that has 2 tri/4 vertices.

if i  set the material up with a texture, i get only a very small portion of the texture drawn on the plane. How can i draw the full texture on the new plane?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to adjust your UV mapping so that the 4 vertices cover the whole image. Take a look at the [this demo file](http://files.scio.de/public/SO/Plane.blend.zip) especially at the UV scene layout.

Comment: i found another way to do this with no UV mapping; i crate a custom plane with the help of this script i pass to the editor: http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php?title=CreatePlane

Comment: @BadescuAlexandru sounds cool. I will use it when creating my next plane :-)

Answer (score 0):

If a texture shows that way it means either the UVs of the imported model are wrong or the texture tilling or offset in the material are wrong.

Instead of importing a mesh for such simple shape you can create one procedurally in code like this: https://github.com/doukasd/Unity-Components/blob/master/ProceduralPlane/Assets/Scripts/Procedural/ProceduralPlane.cs